# can't commit data to the database due to unknown characters in python

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I am scraping some websites and storing the data in my database. Sometimes I get character maps to  error, which I think is due to non-ASCII characters. Since I am scraping many websites with texts in different languages, I could not solve my issue in a general and efficient way.

an error example

```
Message: 'commit exception GRANTS.GOV'
Arguments: (UnicodeEncodeError('charmap', 'The Embassy of the United States in Nur-Sultan and the Consulate General of the United States in Almaty announces an open competition for past participants (“alumni”) of U.S. government-funded and U.S. government-sponsored exchange programs to submit applications to the 2021 Alumni Engagement Innovation Fund (AEIF) 2021.\xa0\xa0We seek proposals from teams of at least two alumni that meet all program eligibility requirements below. Exchange alumni interested in participating in AEIF 2021 should submit proposals to KazakhstanAlumni@state.gov\xa0by March 31, 2021, 18:00 Nur-Sultan time.\xa0\nAEIF provides alumni of U.S. sponsored and facilitated exchange programs with funding to expand on skills gained during their exchange experience to design and implement innovative solutions to global challenges facing their community. Since its inception in 2011, AEIF has funded nearly 500 alumni-led projects around the world through a competitive global competition.\n\nThis year, the U.S. Mission to Kazakhstan will accept proposals managed by teams of at least two (2) alumni that support the following theme:\n\u25cf\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Mental health awareness, promotion of mental wellbeing and resiliency.\nGoals. Projects may support one or more of the following goals:\nGoal 1: Increase in public understanding of mental health issues,\xa0its signs and strategies for providing timely help;\nGoal 2: Increase in public understanding of resources, methods, and tools that promote mental health and resiliency, especially among at-risk audiences; American best practices to promote mental health.\nGoal 3: Combatting stigma around mental health issues and dispelling common myths.\n\nFor full package of required forms please Related Documents section.', 1098, 1099, 'character maps to <undefined>'),)
```

my code :

```
   title ='..............'
   description ='......'
    op = Op(
        website='',
        op_link='',
        title='it might be a long text coming form websites,
        description= it might be a long text coming from websites.,
        organization_id=org_id,
        close_date=',
        checksum=singleData['checksum'],
        published_date='',
        language_id=lang_id,
        is_open=1)
    try:
        session.add(op)
        session.commit()
        session.flush()
        ....
        ....
```

Please note: it should work on a Linux system; my database (Mysql) is in a Linux system.
I mostly face the issue with title and description, which can be in many languages and any length. How can I make encode it correctly so that I don't get any error while committing to the database?

Thank you

Comment: FYI ‘Scrapping’ means throwing away - the correct term is ‘scraping’.

Comment: Show us the *stack trace and the exact error message*. Though, at a guess, it looks like your database table is not expecting non-ascii characters. We also need to know what DBMS you are sending the data to.

Comment: @BoarGules I have given an error example above. you are right. my DBMS is not expecting non-ASCII characters. how to remove all those characters before storing the final text in the database. I am using the MySQL database. as I also previously mentioned that the data might not be in English as well. it can be in any language, Although I want to remove all non-Ascii characters but don't want to lose other language alphabets. could you suggest me any solution

Comment: @BoarGules The error I get is Character map to undefined

Comment: You could try the module `unidecode` https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode which aggressively strips out accents, so it replaces 'á' and 'â' and 'ã' and 'ä' all with 'a'. But that will only work (if you can call it *working*) with languages that use mostly Latin characters. It won't work all that well with non-Latin scripts (such as Cyrillic, Indic or East Asian). For example it renders 'АБВГДЕЖЗ' (Russian alphabet 1-8) as 'ABVGDEZhZ'. If you want a general solution and you have control over the database, then I suggest you redefine your table to use MySQL's `utf8mb4` character set.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you, I will try to do as u suggested.